# Associated workflow links to wrong destination workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

In a site with a number of lists and workflows, lets focus on two, which I'm viewing in SharePoint Designer

List-A > Workflow-A and List-B > Workflow-B

**The problem**:

When I go to view List-B details, I see the box in the lower right for "Workflows" that says "A list of workflows associated with this list."

The top workflow in the list is "Workflow-B" ...ok, all is well.

However, if I click on that link to "Workflow-B" I'm actually arriving at "Workflow-A" details view on the other side.

Everything I can see between List-A and Workflow-A seems to link together as it should.  And  it APPEARS to be ok with List-B/Workflow-B, except for when I follow that link.

This was brought to our attention because occasionally, when we think Workflow-B should fire and run, its failing.  Looking into it we found this link oddity, and wonder if sometimes it isn't firing the wrong one by chance.

Suggestions on correcting this linkage?

Comment: Additional Information: 
> SharePoint 2010 Enterprise
> The workflow seems to work most of the time, but breaks maybe once a month.
> Not sure if the workflow "breaking" is related to the list/workflow incorrect linking, but sure seems suspicious.

Comment: Further information:  To debug, I also drilled into "SharePoint Designer" > "All Files" > "Workflows" > Workflow A & B "xoml.wfconfig.xml" files > And the "Association ListID & TaskListID" are both pointed to the correct GUID values for the list and tasks they should be doing.  This was another place I had read could be off, but it's looking right there as well.